# When I submit Login form , the page just keeps loading and nothing happens (Passport)

Tags: node.js, passport-local

This is the code

```
const passport = require('passport')
const localStrategy = require('passport-local');

//Initializing Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate))

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

This is my Login Route

```
app.post('/login' , passport.authenticate('local' , {failureFlash: true , failureRedirect: '/register'}) , (req , res) => {
    res.redirect('/home')
})
```

This is the HTML

```
<div class="full-container">
        <div class="column-1">
            <div class="column-content">
            <img class="thunder" src="/Thunder.png" alt="">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
            <p>Manage Your Employees Like No Other</p>
            <div class="google-btn">
               <a href="/google"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark google-button mt-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="1.5em" width="1.5em"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path
                        d="M881 442.4H519.7v148.5h206.4c-8.9 48-35.9 88.6-76.6 115.8-34.4 23-78.3 36.6-129.9 36.6-99.9 0-184.4-67.5-214.6-158.2-7.6-23-12-47.6-12-72.9s4.4-49.9 12-72.9c30.3-90.6 114.8-158.1 214.7-158.1 56.3 0 106.8 19.4 146.6 57.4l110-110.1c-66.5-62-153.2-100-256.6-100-149.9 0-279.6 86-342.7 211.4-26 51.8-40.8 110.4-40.8 172.4S151 632.8 177 684.6C240.1 810 369.8 896 519.7 896c103.6 0 190.4-34.4 253.8-93 72.5-66.8 114.4-165.2 114.4-282.1 0-27.2-2.4-53.3-6.9-78.5z">
                    </path>
                </svg>Sign In Using Google</button></a>

                <div class="separator d-flex mt-5 justify-content-center">
                    <hr>
                    <p>Or Sign-in with Company</p>
                    <hr class="second-hr">
                </div>

                <form action="/login" method="post" novalidate class="mt-4">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="username" class="form-label">Company Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username"  placeholder="HZ" name="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Min 8 Characters" name="password">
                       <a href=""><div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">Forgot Password?</div></a>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn  mt-3 submit-btn">LOGIN</button>
                </form>

                <p class="create-account mt-4">Not registered yet ? <a href="/register"><span>Create An Account</span></a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I submit the form , nothing happens , It just keeps loading and loading , no result , any idea what is going on ? Any help is highly appreciated Thank you.

Comment: I doubt that this issue cannot be solved by looking into backend code alone. Can you also attach your HTML code, so that we can find if there's something wrong with HTML?

Comment: I have edited it , you can take a look at the html now @GaneshBabu